# Can spark-submit upload dependencies using WebHDFS?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit

I would like to have the option to not use the IPC ports for DFS for datanodes. WebHDFS seems like a good use case for small-medium files, is there configuration I can provide to the binary to leverage WebHDFS?

I've tried most things, but there doesn't seem to be a very obvious way of doing it.